# Adjusting the JButton size and putting it as a small button in the middle of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, size, jframe, jbutton

```
JFrame menu;

 private void menuFrame() {
        menu = new JFrame();
        menu.setSize(600, 600);
        menu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        menu.setResizable(false);
        menu.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(4,5));
        menu.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(15, 81, 162));
        JButton game = new JButton("New Game");
        game.addActionListener(this);
        menu.getContentPane().add(game);
        JButton multi = new JButton("MultiPlayer");
        menu.getContentPane().add(multi);
        JButton howTo = new JButton("How to Play");
        menu.getContentPane().add(howTo);
        JButton credits = new JButton("Credits");
        menu.getContentPane().add(credits);

        menu.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I have two questions:

1. For the menu frame, i want to have a background then small buttons placed from center north down center south, the problem that i get is that the buttons are placed below each other but their size is the whole width of the JFrame even after using setSize on it
2. How to put an image as a background for the menu JFrame?

Comment: For that 2nd one you really should search the site.  It has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 0):

> then small buttons placed from center north down center south

Try a vertical [Box Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).